# Replace elements of indexed list by list of rules

Tags: replacement, index, indexed-variable

I have an array `bs` that contains many indexed elements `b[ ]`. I want to define the values of bs by a list of replacement rules. However replacement does not work. It works only if I replace every element individually that is not comfortable if you have many variables.

```
bs = Array[b, 10]
rule1 = bs -> {2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 2}
(* {b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5],b[6],b[7],b[8],b[9],b[10]}->{2,4,1,1,5,2,6,2,5,2} *)

b[1] /. rule1
(* b[1] *)

rule2 = {b[1] -> 2, b[2] -> 4};
b[1] + b[2] /. rule2
(* 6 *)
```

**Summary of solutions for different cases (almost all were given in the answers)**

If we have 1 list we can replace by

`Thread[bs -> {2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 2}]`.

If we have to replace  2 lists we can do

`rule = Flatten@{Thread[bs -> {2, 4}], Thread[as -> {5, 6}]}`

If we want to replace a multidimensional list we can use

`rule=Thread[Flatten[cs] -> Flatten[{{1,2},{3,4}}]]`

and everything together

`rule = Flatten@{Thread[bs -> {2, 4}], Thread[as -> {5, 6}],Thread[Flatten[cs] -> Flatten[{{1,2},{3,4}}]]}`

Comment: Is this approach "comfortable" for your problem ?  :  `Thread[bs -> {2, 4, 1, 1, 5, 2, 6, 2, 5, 2}]` ?

Comment: Works. Comfortable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *However how to define the replacement from 2 lists?*

```
bs = Array[b, 2];
as = Array[a, 2];
rule = Flatten@{Thread[bs -> {2, 4}], Thread[as -> {5, 6}]};
b[1] + a[1] /. rule
```

> `7`

Comment: How to treat 2-dimensional lists? See Edit2.

Comment: @granularbastard if I understand correctly you found out how to do it. I just wanted to mention that `ArrayReshape` is also useful :)